# Xamarin form: Does this give limitation access the libraries

Tags: xamarin, package, .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I have a problem with these packages which I wanted to use on my Xamarin form using .net standard 2.0

```
    Package 'ExifLib.PCL 1.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.165' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Package 'Mobilist.AdvancedTimer.Forms.Plugin 1.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Package 'PCLStorage 1.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Package 'Rg.Plugins.Popup 1.0.4' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Does that mean I can't use this library any more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that mean I can't use this library any more?

No, you should be able to use nearly all libraries that are PCL spec compliant inside of a `.NET Standard 2.0` class library. You can checkout the [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#pcl-compatibility) to see list of PCL profiles with their supported platform and their corresponding .NET Standard supported version.

---

**Package warning explanation**

With `.NET Standard 2.0` and the updated tooling in `.NET Core SDK 2+` the .NET team wanted to make it easier to update or make use of .NET Standard libraries. The issue is that not all NuGet packages have been updated to support a version of .NET Standard. So they introduced a [fallback targeting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/#user-content-reusing-an-existing-net-framework-library) `.NET Framework 4.6.1` which is [nearly 100% compliant](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/514) with .NET Standard (There are some API that are in the `.NET Standard 2.0` spec that are not in `.NET Framework 4.6.1` but they can be brought in via NuGet packages if required). So the warning you see is to inform you that the packages do not conform to a .NET Standard version you are targeting and as such may contain API's that are not executable in your runtimes making use of your `.NET Standard 2.0` library.

Once you have tested that everything is working as expect you can add the `NoWarn="NU1701"` to your `PackageReference` in your `csproj` which will remove the warning. One thing to note adding `NoWarn="NU1701"` to a individual package does not remove the warning for dependencies. To remove those warning you must either include them as PackageReferences (via NuGet) or ignore `NU1701` warning at a project level.

If you run into fallback issues you can adjust the target framework fallback via overriding the `AssetTargetFallback` in your `csproj` to something like:

```
<AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
```