# Translation resources no longer display default translated string after update UWP project to Fall Creators Update

Tags: .net, uwp, mvvmcross, globalization, .net-standard

We have updated an UWP project to the Windows Fall Creators Update. We also updated the supporting class libraries(containing the libraries) to .NET Standard 2.0 from .NET Framework 4.5.1.

We have multiple translated language resources. Before the update the string would return the default string in the `Resources.resx` when no translation was provided(this is done by an external source). But after the update it only shows the placeholder. We use MvvmCross 5.7 `IMvxLanguageBinder` to reach the resources.

Does this problem relate to the update to Fall Creators Update or upgrade to .NET Standard?

[image: csProj]

Comment: From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688230/mvvmcross-core-platform-5-7-0-was-restored-using-netframework-version-v4-6-1), it mentions MvvmCross version 5.7.0 has not been updated to support .NET Standard 2.0 yet. So if you update the MvvmCross  to above 6.0, will the same issue occur?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the upgrade to .NET Standard 2.0 - when you upgrade, the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is no longer present by default. This is however a problem, as the "neutral" languauge is not defined. It is necessary to manually set the default language for the .NET Standard project.

You have two ways to set it:

### .csproj

Double-click the .NET Standard 2.0 project in the Solution Explorer and add the following to the first `PropertyGroup`:

```
<NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
```

### Code

Add a `AssemblyInfo.cs` file to your project and in there add the following attribute:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

Comment: The issue is that the resources has no translations to start with, so setting the NeutralLanguage to a specific language still requires to set at least that language. Or am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't understand this correctly from the question. I would also assume the default would be used. Could you please post the relevant part of your `csproj` where the RESX are declared? I would try to reproduce locally.

Comment: Edited orginal post

Comment: When comparing your csproj to my app, I noticed I have my neutral `.resx` files with `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. I am not sure if that can possibly help, but you can try it out just to make sure

Comment: Does not seem to make difference

Comment: I think it might be an issue with the way the Resource Fallback Process works, but still wonder why this only happened after the update